# Intellij - java field order by type name

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to organize java style using intellij's code style. There is a way to sort by field name, but there is no way to sort by type name. Is there any way to sort by type name?

example)

```
// expect 
private final Aclass bbbb;
private final Bclass cccc;
private final CType  aaaa;

// Currently possible way in intellij
private final CType  aaaa;
private final Aclass bbbb;
private final Bclass cccc;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not yet implemented. Feel free to upvote/comment for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151351